# How to create a new custom instance of admob RewardedVideoAd?

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to create a new separated instance, not the shared one to load 2 different videos from 2 different ad units, for example:

```
RewardedVideoAd ga1 = new RewardedVideoAd();
RewardedVideoAd ga2 = new RewardedVideoAd();
```

any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not request for **multiple** adds at a single time as it will affect the user experience. Instead, you can do this.

Request one add.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"); //your key

    // Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
```

And show it where ever you want using

```
if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
}
```

After using it, on the onRewardedVideoAdClosed method

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    // Load the next rewarded video ad.
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}
```

Hope it helps !! For more info visit [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video).